# How do I make a cell equal to the value of the cell address returned from another cell?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to look up where the first non blank cell is in a row and for the cell (lets call it `G1`) to give back the cell location (lets say it returned `D1`). This is working fine but now I want to set another cell (lets call it `A1`) equal to the content that is inside `D1`. However, setting `A1` equal to `G1` only makes `A1` say `"$D$1"` and not the content that is within `D1` itself. Does anyone know how I can do this?

- `G1` looks for first non blank cell
- `D1` has content that I need
- `A1` has to be set equal to content within `D1` and not just `"$D$1"`

Code:

```
G1=ADDRESS(2,MATCH(TRUE, INDEX((A1:F1<>0),0),0))
```

Answer (score 3):

Skip getting the address and use INDEX:

```
=INDEX(A2:F2,MATCH(TRUE, INDEX((A1:F1<>0),0),0))
```

This will return the value in row 2 where at the column where the first non blank value is found.

Comment: I have tried this already. What I want to do is to be able to manipulate and edit the code once it has appeared in cell A1. All this does is give me the content without being able to edit it. The purpose behind this is because I have to copy and paste over 120 lists of components with 50+ components in each list. When pasting (even when using special paste *text*) it doesnt paste all in the same column. I am trying to avoid having to manually move every single 50+ rows for every 120+ of the lists I must copy. Thus I am just trying to find the first nonblank cell and move itto the first column